Characterisation of finite cyclic groups via free actions
This question appears as exercise 4.E.14 in the book "Geometric Group Theory, An Introduction" by Clara Löh. The exercise says the following:
Find a class $C$ of graphs with the following property: A group is finite cyclic if and only if it admits a free action on some graph in $C$.
So far I have the following argument:
The class $C$ will be the class of finite cycles $C_{n}$ with $n$ edges. So, for example, $C_{2}$ is the graph with two vertices and two edges joining the vertices, and $C_{3}$ will have three vertices and three edges forming a cycle.
And now we check that it satisfies what we want. If your group has two elements it acts freely on $C_{2}$ by interchanging the vertices and edges, if your group is finite cyclic of order $n \geq 3$ then it's Cayley graph with generating set $\{\overline{1}\}\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is $C_{n}$ and G acts freely by proposition 4.1.10 in Clara Löh's book.
For the other implication, we want to understand how does an element $g \in G$ act on $C_{n}$, as the action is free it has to be a rotation by a divisor of $n$ (I'm not completely sure about this, I want to see if this is true), if it were a reflexion it would have either a vertex or and edge fixed. Then also, two different elements in the group induce different rotations because the action is free. Using these two facts I say this and I'm not so sure:
You begin with an element $g_{1} \in G$ and if it doesn't generate the whole group, then take $g_{2} \in G \setminus  \langle g_{1} \rangle $, then if it doesn't generate take $g_{3} \in G \setminus \langle g_{1},g_{2} \rangle $ and so on. I say this "algorithm" stops because in every iteration we have an element of unique order that is a divisor of $n$, and as the number of divisors of $n$ the proccess described stops and it happens that some element $g_{k}$ generates the whole group.
I would love if someone told me if my reasoning is wrong (and could give me a hint in the right direction) or knows another solution to this problem!
